How solve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for Gson when trying to implement Spotify API in SpringBoot project
Getting below error when trying to run my SpringBoot project which implements the SpotifyAPI from MichaelTheLin:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.gson.JsonElement com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(java.lang.String)'
at se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager.getResponseBody(SpotifyHttpManager.java:310) ~[spotify-web-api-java-8.4.0.jar:na]
at se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager.get(SpotifyHttpManager.java:174) ~[spotify-web-api-java-8.4.0.jar:na]
at se.michaelthelin.spotify.requests.AbstractRequest.getJson(AbstractRequest.java:111) ~[spotify-web-api-java-8.4.0.jar:na]
at se.michaelthelin.spotify.requests.data.tracks.GetTrackRequest.execute(GetTrackRequest.java:38) ~[spotify-web-api-java-8.4.0.jar:na]
at com.makersacademy.acebook.service.SpotifyService.getTrack(SpotifyService.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at com.makersacademy.acebook.Application.run(Application.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at com.makersacademy.acebook.Application.main(Application.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]

Seems its an issue resolving the dependency for Gson but not getting any obvious error, and copied over the dependency into my pom.xml from the github docs.
<dependency>
        <groupId>se.michaelthelin.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotify-web-api-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- added dependencies from spotify web api github -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>


More likely the project is using an incorrect version of the dependency. Generate a dependency tree with Maven and look which dependencies are pulling gson versions.

as @aled mentioned the issue is likely related to the incorrect version, you can try to downgrade the dependency version to see if that helps.

You can also try to debug where the Gson classes are loaded from, see Gson Troubleshooting Guide; but replace Gson.class with JsonParser.class.
